# Creating a process without inheriting parent process's environment variable

Tags: process, exec, fork

I have a program which has to start executing another process. But the child process should not inherit the environment from the parent process. i.e. It should be launched as if I had launched the program from explorer. On searching, I found some exec*() functions that allow you to send in an array of strings as environment variables. But this process is cumbersome as I need to strip out my program specific environment vars from the list and send it to the child. Is there any other way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to achieve this is that which you feel is cumbersome. It's really not that difficult though, just some mindless string manipulation.

Comment: The problem is figuring out the environment variables set by the parent program. This is a third party software where you can write programs that can be executed. It also allows you to call other programs as a part of your program!

Comment: I'm not sure why you would care which values were provided by the system, vs. those which were set / modified before you were called, but since you seem to be talking about a Windows system, I would suggest your only option will be to parse the registry for the system environment key, followed by the current user key. I don't know which keys to examine but it shouldn't be difficult to locate. You need to remember though, that values there may refer to other environment variables which you'll need to dereference and substitute in their value.

Comment: The User values are at HKCU\Environment and I found the system values at HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Environment. I'd be weary of the system path though, it looks like it could be variable.